# ImportExportText error when using frontend - you cannot record your changes because a value you entered violates the settings defined for this table

Tags: ms-access

I created a Macro in MS-Access that calls a lot of queries. First, it does a lot of ImportExportText to read 50 text files and write them in a table. It works perfectly but it creates some ImportErrors because some lines of the text are not OK, but it doesn't matter.

The file is too big and it's near the 2 gb limit, so I decided to split it in frontend and backend and it seems to solve all my problems, but when I run the Macro from the frontend, it says:

[You cannot record your changes because a value you entered violates the settings defined for this table or list (for example, a value is less than the minimum or greater than the maximum). Correct the error and try again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DfBi.png)

I suppose it's because it tries to create a table in the frontend and maybe it's not allowed. Could that be the problem? How can I solve it? I tried to create the ImportErrors table manually and I could do that, but the error still appears.

So, if I use the text files in MS-Access file that is just one file (not frontend and backend) it works perfectly. But if I use them in the frontend-backend mode, it fails. How can I solve that?

Thanks!

Comment: Trying to replicate issue. I don't get that error message. Simply get "Unable to append" error message. Edit question to show sample table and sample text file.

Comment: Do you mean uploading the text file? Let me see in which line it occurs (it's a 45 MB text file), but I should also give you the specs that are used to convert the text file to a table. Thanks for the reply